# Group and Stuff multiple rows based on Count condition

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, aggregate

I have a script that runs every 10 minutes and returns table with events from past 24 hours (marked by the script run time)

```
ID      Name                TimeOfEvent                 EventCategory       TeamColor
1       Verlene Bucy        2015-01-30 09:10:00.000         1                   Blue
2       Geneva Rendon       2015-01-30 09:20:00.000         2                   Blue
3       Juliane Hartwig     2015-01-30 09:25:00.000         3                   Blue
4       Vina Dutton         2015-01-30 12:55:00.000         2                   Red
5       Cristin Lewis       2015-01-30 15:50:00.000         2                   Red
6       Reiko Cushman       2015-01-30 17:10:00.000         1                   Red
7       Mallie Temme        2015-01-30 18:35:00.000         3                   Blue
8       Keshia Seip         2015-01-30 19:55:00.000         2                   Blue
9       Rosalia Maher       2015-01-30 20:35:00.000         3                   Red
10      Keven Gabel         2015-01-30 21:25:00.000         3                   Red
```

Now I'd like to select two groups of Names based on these conditions:

1) Select Names from same EventCategory having 4 or more records in past 24 hours.

2) Select Names from same EventCategory and same TeamColor having 2 or more records in past 1 hour.

So my result would be:

```
4+per24h: Geneva Rendon, Vina Dutton, Cristin Lewis, Keshia Seip        EventCategory = 2
4+per24h: Juliane Hartwig, Mallie Temme, Rosalia Maher, Keven Gabel     EventCategory = 3
2+per1h:  Rosalia Maher, Keven Gabel                                    EventCategory = 3, TeamColor = Red
```

For the first one, I have written this:

```
SELECT mt.EventCategory, MAX(mt.[name]), MAX(mt.TimeOfEvent), MAX(mt.TeamColor)
  FROM #mytable mt
GROUP BY mt.EventCategory
HAVING COUNT(mt.EventCategory) >= 4
```

because I don't care for the actual time as long as it's in the past 24 hours (and it always is), but I have trouble stuffing the names in one row.

The second part, I have no idea how to do. Because the results need to have both same EventCategory and TeamColor and also be limited by the one hour bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is possible, but you mix two separate issues. Here you find them combined with `UNION`:

Just paste this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100),TimeOfEvent DATETIME,EventCategory INT,TeamColor VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'Verlene Bucy','2015-01-30T09:10:00.000',1,'Blue')
,(2,'Geneva Rendon','2015-01-30T09:20:00.000',2,'Blue')
,(3,'Juliane Hartwig','2015-01-30T09:25:00.000',3,'Blue')
,(4,'Vina Dutton','2015-01-30T12:55:00.000',2,'Red')
,(5,'Cristin Lewis','2015-01-30T15:50:00.000',2,'Red')
,(6,'Reiko Cushman','2015-01-30T17:10:00.000',1,'Red')
,(7,'Mallie Temme','2015-01-30T18:35:00.000',3,'Blue')
,(8,'Keshia Seip','2015-01-30T19:55:00.000',2,'Blue')
,(9,'Rosalia Maher','2015-01-30T20:35:00.000',3,'Red')
,(10,'Keven Gabel','2015-01-30T21:25:00.000',3,'Red');

WITH Extended AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2015-01-30T21:26:00.000',TimeOfEvent) AS MinuteDiff --use GETDATE() here...
          ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY EventCategory) AS CountCategory
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)
,Filtered24Hours AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Extended
    WHERE CountCategory >=4
)
,Filtered60Mins AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Extended
    WHERE MinuteDiff >=-60 
      AND CountCategory >=2
)
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Filtered24Hours AS x WHERE x.EventCategory=outerSource.EventCategory) AS CountNames
               ,'per24h' AS TimeIntervall
               ,STUFF((
                        SELECT ' ,' + innerSource.Name 
                        FROM Filtered24Hours AS innerSource
                        WHERE innerSource.EventCategory=outerSource.EventCategory
                        ORDER BY innerSource.TimeOfEvent
                        FOR XML PATH('') 
                       ),1,2,'') AS Names 
              ,EventCategory 
              ,NULL
FROM Filtered24Hours AS outerSource
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Filtered60Mins AS x WHERE x.EventCategory=outerSource.EventCategory) 
               ,'per1h'
               ,STUFF((
                        SELECT ' ,' + innerSource.Name 
                        FROM Filtered60Mins AS innerSource
                        WHERE innerSource.EventCategory=outerSource.EventCategory
                        ORDER BY innerSource.TimeOfEvent
                        FOR XML PATH('') 
                       ),1,2,'') 
              ,EventCategory 
              ,TeamColor
FROM Filtered60Mins AS outerSource
```

The result

```
Count Interv    Names                                                     Category  Team
4     per24h    Geneva Rendon ,Vina Dutton ,Cristin Lewis ,Keshia Seip    2         NULL
4     per24h    Juliane Hartwig ,Mallie Temme ,Rosalia Maher ,Keven Gabel 3         NULL
2     per1h     Rosalia Maher ,Keven Gabel                                3         Red
```

Comment: I only had a minute to test it, but my sql-server 2005 couldn't cope with "WITH Extended AS". I'll have a proper look later.

Comment: @Zikato, I could not test this on SQLServer 2005, but `WITH myCTE` [should work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175972%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)...  Be aware that the `WITH myCTE` **must** be separated from the line before with a semicolon. Therefore it is quite common to use `;WITH...` (see the semicolon before the WITH ?) everywhere...

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem. The solution works, now I just need to study it for a bit to learn why. I was unfamiliar with WITH statements until this point.

Comment: Small problem, when I change the time, so the last 4 rows happen in the same hour, they Rosalia Maher, etc gets reported twice and Keisha Seip is reported alone for some reason. I don't think there is a condition that per1h must have same category AND same team. But I will look into it myself, I just wanted you to know.